# HTML onClick not working on server

Tags: javascript, html

This code is working on local host but button onClick is not working on a different server.

```
      <form name="myform" method="POST" id="location"> 
        <input type="text" name="URL" id="filename" maxlength="255" size="100" /> 
        <br /> <br /> 
        <button type="button" onClick="callViewXML()">Submit Query</button>
      </form>
```

Definition of callViewXML:

```
function callViewXML(){

  alert('callViewXML');
  var file= document.getElementById("filename").value;
  if(file == "")
  {
   alert("No XML file is provided.Field is blank");
  }
  else{
   //alert(file);
   viewXML(file);
 }
}
```

I am not able to find the reason why it is not working when I am uploading it on a server and testing it.
I am using Firefox browser.
When I click the button (server code) it says "ReferenceError: callViewXML is not defined"..but that error does not occur on local host.

Comment: The JavaScript `onclick` should not be affected with everything being the same on the server, could you explain how it's "not working", any errors?

Comment: How did you debug your code so far? What have you found out?

Comment: Probably the filename you enter is not a real file on your server

Comment: `viewXML()`? What is that? It's not working? What do you mean by that?

Comment: when i click the button (server code) it says "ReferenceError: callViewXML is not defined"..but that error does not occur on local host.

Comment: Did you get the alert 'callViewXML'?

Comment: no i am not getting alert message

Comment: Have you tested any other browsers? I'm looking into your error. Where are you including your javascript?

Comment: same problem in other browsers as well.I have included it in BODY for now..but i have tested by keeping it in header as well. Didnt work.

Comment: This error basically means that you're calling your function before it's being defined, so moving your script lower in the document (like, let's say the footer) or even defining your "onclick" event in your script file (if you're using jquery) should do the trick. If you want, I can write an answer with some sample code for how this would work in jquery.

Comment: I cannot use jquery here. I will try moving it in footer and check that.

Comment: You could also try using element.addEventListener('click', function(event){...});

Comment: I bet the filename for your JavaScript file is not exactly the same name. The case of the filename is probably different. A windows machine won't care, but your server might. If you check the Network log I bet you are getting a 404 response.